# How good is my approximation of this complicated sinc function? (plot included)

Tags: integration, approximation

**Part 1:**
The following function (for $N=256$) has the plot shown nexr

$$
 G(x) = \frac{1}{N}\text{exp} \bigg( j \frac{\pi}{2} \,  x(N-1)\bigg) \frac{\sin (\frac{\pi N}{2}  x)}{\sin  (\frac{\pi}{2}  x )}$$

$$G(0)=1$$
                     [image]

A good approximation of this function would be the piecewise function given next  $$G_a(x) = \left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
     1 & \mbox{if $ - \frac{2}{N}\leq x \leq \frac{2}{N} $};\\
     0 & \mbox{if $\mbox{OW}$}.\end{array} \right. $$

**Part 2:**
Assume I have a function $$f(y) = \int_{-2}^{2}\frac{f_X(x)}{1+y^{-3}|G(x)|^2}\, dx$$ with  $$0<f_X(x) <1, \,\,\,\,\,\,\ \int_{-2}^{2}f_X(x)\, dx=1 $$
$$f_X(x) =\int_{\max\{-1,-1-x\}}^{\min\{1,1-x\}} \left(\frac{1}{\pi^2 \sqrt{1-(x+v)^2}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-v^2}}\right) dv $$

If I use the approximate $G_a(x)$ ( which is way easier than the original function) then I can approximate $f(y)$ by $$f_a(y)=  \int_{-2}^{N/2} f_X(x)\, dx + \int_{N/2}^{2} f_X(x)\, dx + \int_{-N/2}^{N/2}\frac{f_X(x)}{1+y^{-3}} \, dx $$

**Question**
Which is correct $$f_a(y)>f(y)$$  $$f_a(y)<f(y)$$

Thanks

Comment: What is $j$? ($\sqrt{-1}$?) What are $\Delta_t$ and $\epsilon$?

Comment: @BaronVT yes for the imaginary, I am  very sorry the variables you mentioned where typos. I fixed it.

Comment: Ok, a little playing around in matlab, and I don't think either statement is generally true (i.e. for a general $f_X$ satisfying your conditions, and a general $y \in (-2,2)$), do you have some reason to believe otherwise? (I chose $f_X = \dfrac{3}{16}x^2$, flipping the sign on $y$ seems to flip the inequality, the two are closer as $|y| \to 2$.)

Comment: I will update the question, and give you the exact function $f_X(x)$, I thought it that it doesn't really add value whether I include it, so I decided not to include it. I included these type of conditions because the $f_X(x)$ is a probability density function and is itself very hard to compute. That is the reason I approximate the function $G(x)$. Please let me know what you think. @BaronVT

Comment: ok, I will take a look at it later. here is my matlab code if you want to play around with it: http://pastebin.com/CFUX4Eak

Comment: (Though N should be 256 of course, I was messing around and forgot to change it back)

Comment: Ok @Tyrone, I implemented your function, and assuming I didn't do anything wrong (not necessarily a safe assumption), I still don't think either inequality holds generally. Here is my code: http://pastebin.com/3XaRMG9S and here is a screenshot of the output: http://i.imgur.com/5wRNkW6.png